# Ошибка при установке библиотеки aiogram

Tags: python, visual-studio, библиотеки, установка

Я хочу установить `aiogram`, версия Python 3.12, вываливает такое:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools"
```

Ну и далее ссылка на установку буилд тулс, и еще снизу написано что ошибка не в pip, я установил что он просил, но ситуация осталась такой же,
что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Друг, я не нашел ответ на это в интернете, но помогло одно. Скорее всего, версия python просто не подходит. С python 3.12 мне выдавало эту ошибку, а с python 3.11 все заработало. Попробуй.

Comment: Да я уже решил эту проблему, в документации увидел что не выпустили еще поддержку 3.12, сделал откат до 3.11.4 и все заработало, но все равно спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Для начала попробуйте выполнить следующую команду и повторить установку проблемной библиотеки:

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Если ошибка по-прежнему осталась, скорее всего неверно указан или вовсе отсутствует путь до сборщика в «переменных средах». Кликните ПКМ на кнопке «Пуск» и выберите пункт «Система», а в открывшемся окне «Параметров» нажмите на «Дополнительные параметры системы» и в открывшемся окне «свойства системы» нажмите кнопку «Параметры среды». В окне «Переменные среды пользователя хххх» выберите строку «Path» и нажмите «Изменить». Посмотрите внимательно по списку, нет ли в нем строки, содержащей что-то вроде «C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64». Это путь при стандартной установке VS. В зависимости от версии установленных VS, пакета MSVC, разрядности сборщика и раздела, который был выбран при установке, в вашем случае путь может отличаться. Если путь к сборщику отсутствует, нажмите кнопку «Создать» и вставьте путь. После этого желательно перезапустить виртуальную среду, в которой вы работаете со своим Python приложением, а в некоторых случаях может потребоваться перезапуск системы.

Если же вы все еще сталкиваетесь с этой ошибкой, то вероятнее всего, ранее у вас уже был установлен Visual Studio другой версии, либо он был неверно сконфигурирован, из-за чего в реестре могли остаться «следы», препятствующие запуску сборщика. Откройте «Редактор реестра» и перейдите в ветку «HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun». Если она существует, удалите ее (только «AutoRun»). Тоже самое проделайте с веткой «HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun». Может потребоваться перезаход в систему. Теперь попробуйте выполнить установку проблемной библиотеки.

---

[Источник](https://dzen.ru/a/ZP14SK5QkB0uoy9t)

Comment: Здравствуйте. в любом случае спасибо за развернутый ответ,НО это не помогло действия в реестре как и ожидалось были бесполезны так как старую версию я деинсталировал корректно,  ну а всё то что вы сказали выше я сделал и это не помогло( Хрен с этим уже аёграмом, третий день уже с ним мучаюсь, на другой библиотеке сделаю уже бота

Comment: Правильно, я думаю это "особая" проблема вашего компьютера

Comment: Аккуратнее, за такие слова здесь банят.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать